# What are 'ForYou nudges'?

Tags: support, tags, moderator-tools, terminology, tag-merge-utility

I just did a tag merge; that always gives a rather technical summary of what database records have been updated. I understand most of the messages, but I'm puzzled by the ForYou nudges (this particular tag didn't have them, apparently). What are they?

```
updating post history, 8 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 7 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 6 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
...
```

Comment: "For You" is an SO for Teams thing AFAIK. I would guess they nudge someone or something involved with a tag on SO for Teams?

Comment: Oh no, it's the sad story of [Emoji Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/17/saying-thanks-testing-a-new-reactions-feature) all over again. :-(

Comment: @Cody eww, I forgot about it by now, now grossed all over again, lol. But yeah it makes sense the table holding the selected emojis will be called ForYou, good catch!

Comment: Heh, I realize now that 1) this title wouldn't really stand out in a collection of spam posts 2) this feature might still be in development, and we accidentally stumbled upon it ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm a PM on the SO for Teams side.

Nudges are the reminders to answer a question. If you're watching a tag, or are a Subject Matter Experts (SME) for a tag, and a question remains unanswered for a certain amount of time, then this "nudge" is generated.

When merging tags, these nudge notifications need to be updated, which is what you're seeing in that log.

Comment: What is "SME"? Some people are still not using Teams, so we don't know the internal jargon. :/ (Half the answer makes sense, half I just don't understand.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Subject Matter Expert, this is a general term and not specific for Teams, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert for example.

Comment: @Marijn thanks, but I never heard that used (or don't remember hearing) and Google didn't give it in the results, only non relevant things like "Small and medium-sized enterprises". But what is it in context of Stack Overflow tags? How can one become expert in a tag? Sounds like Teams feature?

Comment: @Shadow it is also in the [Glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/). There it is connected to tag badges, maybe that is how people are identified for these nudges.

Comment: @Marijn that's fair. Would still like some more details though. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars: Yes, users or user groups can be added as subject matter experts for a tag on Teams.

Comment: @V2Blast nice, and they get special icon next to their name?

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars If they answer a question with a tag they're an SME for, there is an [indicator at the top of the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnlG7.png) that the person who answered is an SME.