# How to read the "tag merge" log

Tags: support, tags, moderator-tools, tag-merge-utility

Site moderators have a tool to merge tags. As a result of such a merge, a popup window with a log appears, e.g. [here is a recent merging](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12930/176217):

```
updating post history, 130 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 112 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 90 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'телеграм': [телеграм] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 2293
tag remapping of [telegram] and [телеграм] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
3 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym телеграм -> telegram was approved!
```

Some lines looks obvious, but not all of them. How should these lines be interpreted?

A line by line explanation will be very appreciated.

Comment: Which parts are more 'confusing' ?  I suspect they're just exposing the internal logics to us, like the "pipe delimited" and "ForYou" Nudges are a teamism, for example

Comment: Yeah, the [ForYou nudges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385529/295232) were a mystery to me too...