# Question merge log still mentions 'bookmarks' instead of 'saves'

Tags: bug, bookmarks, merged-questions, saves

When merging two questions, the log mentions 'bookmarks' in the next-to-last line, even though [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/295232):

```
Beginning merge of question.Id = 396316 into question.Id = 176961 

Moved 2 answers to master
Moved 0 answer flags to master answers
Moved 2 comments to master
Moved 0 comment flags to master comments
Moved 0 favorite votes to master 
Master now has 4 active answers 
Master now has 3 active comments 

Master now has 0 bookmarks 
Successful merge
```

Answer (score 2):

Since such logs are used for, I would say, almost internal purposes (moderators are closer to staff than regular users) then probably descriptions (such as variable and function names) inside the code base will remain the same, and there's actually no need to change their names.

For instance, I have a (not yet answered) [question for sibling log about the tag merging tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392391/339911). That log contains even weirder terminology that is not revealed to normal users by the system.